# Is there a function in R that generates a table of pre-existing combinations in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with data that looks like

[image]

There a numerous organisms `org` and corresponding Abx. class names such as `Penicillins`, `Aminoglycosides`, and `Trimethoprim`.

My desired output is a table that lists:

1. All possible combinations (e.g. acito+ Aminoglycosides, acito + Carbapenems, Hemop + Carbapenems )
2. List how many 0 and 1 are present for each combination

I am unable to move forward despite trying features from `{tidyverse}` and `expand.grid()`.

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please provide some usable test data and define the output you expect based on that test data.  FWIW, you are on one possible right track with `expand.grid` and the tidyverse.

Answer (score 1):

An answer to your first question

> All possible combinations (e.g. acito+ Aminoglycosides, acito + Carbapenems, Hemop + Carbapenems )

might be

```
expand.grid(sort(unique(xyzzy$org)), colnames(xyzzy)[-1])
```

which gives

```
    Var1            Var2
1  acito     Penicillins
2  hemop     Penicillins
3   kleb     Penicillins
4  psudo     Penicillins
5  acito Aminoglycosides
6  hemop Aminoglycosides
7   kleb Aminoglycosides
8  psudo Aminoglycosides
9  acito    Trimethoprim
10 hemop    Trimethoprim
11  kleb    Trimethoprim
12 psudo    Trimethoprim
```

And to your second question

> List how many 0 and 1 are present for each combination

the answer might be two basic `aggregate` lines:

```
aggregate(xyzzy[, -1], list(org = xyzzy$org), \(x) sum(x == 0))
aggregate(xyzzy[, -1], list(org = xyzzy$org), \(x) sum(x == 1))
```

gives

```
> aggregate(xyzzy[, -1], list(org = xyzzy$org), \(x) sum(x == 0))
    org Penicillins Aminoglycosides Trimethoprim
1 acito          NA               7           NA
2 hemop           1              NA           NA
3  kleb           2               2           NA
4 psudo          NA               1           NA
> aggregate(xyzzy[, -1], list(org = xyzzy$org), \(x) sum(x == 1))
    org Penicillins Aminoglycosides Trimethoprim
1 acito          NA               0           NA
2 hemop           0              NA           NA
3  kleb           0               0           NA
4 psudo          NA               1           NA
```

---

Data:

```
xyzzy = read.table(text = "org Penicillins Aminoglycosides Trimethoprim
kleb 0 0 NA
acito NA 0 NA
hemop 0 NA NA
psudo NA 1 NA
acito NA 0 NA
acito NA 0 NA
psudo NA 0 NA
acito NA 0 NA
kleb 0 0 NA
acito NA 0 NA
acito NA 0 NA
acito NA 0 NA", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: #Create combinations using the specified columns
result <- expand.grid(org_values = sort(unique(filtered_mergedfinal$org)),
                      selected_columns)
#remove other and contaminant from the org column 
filtered_result <- result %>% filter(!grepl("other|contaminant", org_values))
These codes worked to answer part 1 of the question

Comment: However, codes (aggregate) to answer part 2 of the question are not working. The output I need is that beside the var 1 and var 2 column should be 2 more columns titles 0 and 1. and the details within these 2 columns should be number of 0s and 1s for that specific combination (e.g. acito     Penicillins)

Comment: That is not stated in your question. Also, your concrete ideas how the table(s) should be arranged is more or less a follow-up-question. In the future, make sure to elaborate on your expected/desired result.